# htaccess regex vs php regex

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I've been using apache + htaccess for matching URL's for years now. We're going to be updating our entire platform soon and I'm wondering if switching to URL matching in php would have any performance impact.

We are using Apache right now (obviously) however with URL's being matched in PHP would free us to explore alternatives such as nginx+php.

Would this be a good or bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did exactly this, setup a table in MySQL of URL's and PHP would do a `preg_match` against each URL rule before deciding what action to take. Then we had a single mod_rewrite rule that pushes every URL through one script.

This worked great for us and gives us much more flexibility without having to create hundreds of physcial files for different rules.

We receive 15m unique hits a month and haven't experienced any issues with this, providing your using suitable caching of the URL's.

Answer (score 0):

Matching urls in php is extremly pleasant after apache - you can debug your pattern, and everything works as expected. In my MVC framework I have router, that matches `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . ':' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` against route regexps - very comfortable for SEO needs.

The only hint: do not use php to match and output static files - it is very slow. There are no other impacts on performance.

Answer (score -1):

Apache is a huge performance impact itself. As long as you are using it, you may worry of no other impacts.

Comment: Suggesting a different web server?